# Escape methods within single qoutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am using the gmaps4rails gem and building my own markers json in my controller, but because it is in single qoutes it does not recognize my variables (@claim.longitude). Is it possible to escape the single qoutes, or is there another way to do this?

```
@markers = '[{"description": "", "title": "My Location: Seattle", "sidebar": "",
         "lng": "#{@claim.longitude}", "lat": "#{@claim.latitude}", 
         "picture": "", "width": "", "height": ""}]'
```

Comment: Just switch them... double quotes on the outside and single quotes on the inside.

Answer (score 3):

Let Rails create the JSON for you.

```
> json_string = [{"foo" => "bar", "fred" => "barney"}].to_json
> puts json_string
[{"fred":"barney","foo":"bar"}]
```

If you get to the point where you want to convert your models into JSON, then look up the `as_json` method as well.